# MongoDB, Grouping by Multiple Fields

Tags: mongodb

pretty new to Mongo and am finding some simple things that i would do in SQL frustratingly difficult in Mongo.

I have an object similar to this below

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5870fb29a1fe030e1a2909db"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-01-07T14:28:57.224Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-07T14:28:57.224Z"),
    "state" : "Available",
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5870fb29a1fe030e1a2909dc"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-01-07T14:28:57.224Z"),
   "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-07T14:28:57.224Z"),
   "state" : "notReady",
},
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5870fb29a1fe030e1a2909d9"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-01-07T14:28:57.224Z"),
   "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-07T14:28:57.224Z"),
   "state" : "Disconnected",
}]
```

What i'm looking to do it group the data by the Maximum date and the state.
Ideally the result i would be looking for would be something like the following.

```
{
latestDate: "2017-01-07T14:28:57",
states : {
  available : 10,
  disconnected : 5,
  notReady : 2
}}
```

Basically i'm looking for the SQL equivalent of this:

```
SELECT createdAt, state, COUNT(rowid)
FROM db
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(createdAt) FROM db)
GROUP BY 1,2
```

I've searched around here and have found some good info but am probably missing something straight forward. Ive only managed to get here so far

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$project: {"_id" : 0,"state": 1, "date" : "$createdAt"}},
{$group :  {"_id" : {"date":"$date", "state": "actual"}, "count":{"$sum":1}}}
])
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $group : {
        _id : {
            date : "$createdAt",
            state : "$state"
        },
        count : {$sum : 1}
    }
},
{
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id.date",
        states : {
            $addToSet : {
                state : "$_id.state",
                count : "$count"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $sort : {_id : -1}
},
{
    $limit : 1
},
{
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        latestDate : "$_id",
        states : "$states"
    }
}
])
```

output :

```
{
    "latestDate" : ISODate("2017-01-07T14:28:57.224Z"),
    "states" : [
             {
                     "state" : "Available",
                     "count" : 1
             },
             {
                     "state" : "notReady",
                     "count" : 1
             },
             {
                     "state" : "Disconnected",
                     "count" : 1
             }
     ]
}
```

Comment: excellent ares I can work with this. need to study up to understand this a little bit better thought. thanks for the help.